# How to check the values from the array in the loop

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php $callout = array(
    '1', 
    '3', 
    '5'
); ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($callout as $call) { ?> 
    <li>
        <h3><?php echo get_the_title($call); ?></h3>
        <p>different text goes here...</p>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Is it possible - if $call=1 then echo some static text, if 2 echo something else, and so on?

Comment: use php `if-else` statement or `switch`

Comment: refer to this .I guess it will help you  http://codepad.org/0mZIkJuB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Thanks to [@swapnesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/639406/swapnesh)

http://codepad.org/0mZIkJuB

```
<?php $callout = array(1,2,3); ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($callout as $call) { ?> 
    <li>
        <?php
            if ('1' == $call)
                echo "a";
            elseif ('2' == $call)
                echo "b";
            elseif ('3' == $call)
                echo "c";
            else
                echo "d";
        ?>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```